# Not able to get successful connection message after retry using web socket

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

I have been using rxjs WebSocket service for making WebSocket connection. I am developing one of the functionality which requires a message after making the successful reconnection in angular 6 application. Currently, rxjs retry function doesn't provide any successful
subscribe method or response method from WebSocket.
Following is the code to make a retry connection using rxjs web socket.

```
this.socket$ = Websocket("ws://10.12.12.12:4040")
this.socket$.retry().subscribe((success) => {
console.log(success);
},(error) => {
console.log(error);
}, (complete) => {
console.log(complete);
});
```

Above code works when connection appears successfully but we are not able to catch that connection is been established successfully. Even we have also tried with `retryWhen()` but no success.
Need to identify which method is been used to get a success response in order to display Connection established is successful to the end user.